# In r, how do I add rows together to get totals for a specific set of variables

Tags: r

My goal is to have a list of how much FDI China sent to each country per year. At the moment I have a list of individual projects that looks like this

| Year | Country | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | Angola | 6000000 |
| 2001 | Angola | 8000000 |
| 2001 | Angola | 5.0E7 |

I want to sum it so it looks like this.

| Year | Country | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2001 | Angola | 6.4E7 |

How do I merge the rows and add the totals to get nice country-year data? I can't find an R command that does this precise thing.

Comment: You can use `aggregate(Amount ~ ., df1, sum)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I copied the data table and read your dataframe into R using:

```
df <- clipr::read_clip_tbl(clipr::read_clip())
```

I like using dplyr to solve this question:

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(df %>% group_by(Country,Year) %>% summarize(Amount=sum(Amount)))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   Country [1]
  Country  Year   Amount
  <chr>   <int>    <dbl>
1 Angola   2001 64000000
```

Comment: I got an error message 

Error in data3 %>% group_by(recipient_cow_code, Year) %>% summarize(usd_current = sum(usd_current)) : 
  could not find function "%>%"

Comment: i think the dplyr package is masked by another pakcage. please run rm(list=ls())  at the beginning of the script and load only tidyverse and not purr and tell us what you see

Comment: Perhaps plyr is the issue?

Comment: make sure dplyr is installed and loaded before running the script, @somedude

Comment: I installed dplyr, still the same error message. No result from rm(list=ls())

Comment: Do you see dplyr and/or plyr loaded in the packages tab? @somedude

Comment: I turned on dplyr and it outputted a bunch of (what I think is) merged data in the console. If I can turn that into a dataframe I'm done.

Comment: @somedude See my edit :) you just have to assign it to a dataframe structure. The output was a tibble but I prefer to have everything in a dataframe